# Javascript: How to display text if an image exists

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement

I have been trying to create a code like this:

If you show 'us.gif' in the div id 'yourCountry', display this css code:
--- #yourCountry img{display:none} ---
End of the if

I have tried to do it and searched about it on the web, but nothing has worked for me.

This is how I was attempting to achieve it with javascript (I am a newbie with javascript):

```
<script language=javascript>
<!--
function usimage ()  {
if document.images["us.gif"]  {
document.write("
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body div div div div div div div div form div div div table td img{display:none;} 
-->
</style>
");}}
</script>
```

Comment: just a suggestion, you may want to check out something like jquery or mootools. This would be pretty easy with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JS is a bit messy, would a CSS 2.1 selector be acceptable?

`div#yourCountry img[src="us.gif"] { display:none; }`

Comment: Yes, you are totally right! I did this and worked on all the modern browsers FF IE Opera Safari: 

body div div div div div div div div form div div div table td img[src="http://feed.ncsreporting.com/CoBrandWebFeed/Images/us.gif"] { display:none; } 
  
It did not work by naming the div in CSS (dont know why). I am working with Wordpress stylesheet. Obviously it doesn't work on IE 6, but who cares?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<script language=javascript>
function usimage ()  {
    for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; ++i)
    {
        if(document.images[i].src.search("us.gif") >= 0)
        {
            document.write('<style type="text/css">'
                +'<!--'
                +'body div div div div div div div div form div div div table td img{display:none;} '
                +'-->'
                +'</style>'
            );
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

P/S: You don't understand clearly about js language. Your code is wrong so much like you don't know any language.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am not a programmer. Thank you anyway for your help!